# Conceptual Question on probability of tossing a coin problem as many as number of times

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, descriptive-statistics

If we toss a coin as many as number of times , The probability of getting head or tail comes out to be almost half. I know this very well. But in real life scenario nobody is going to toss a coin 1000, 100000 or even more number of times , Then what's the significance of the above problem ? What are we trying to understand ?

Comment: Note: it will approach a 50-50 split for a fair coin, a biased coin will have differing probabilities for heads and tails. 

There are a few things to take from such scenarios. One is that a small sample size may not be truthfully representative of the true probability but with more and more trials it will approach the true probability. Another, is it leads to other questions for instance, if we toss a fair/biased coin 1000 times what is the probability we get a run of 100 heads, etc.

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting here?  Perhaps people rarely toss a coin thousands of times, but they certainly sample the height (or hair color, or weight, etc.) of thousands of individuals and it's important to know what that sample data tells us about the "true" distribution of those variables.